# ElasticSearch returning no results despite correct query

Tags: php, elasticsearch, filebeat

I have created an index named filebeat in elasticsearch.The log data is being sent in elasticsearch by filebeat agent.
I want to filter the results based on a particular column/field named value_of_type. Using PHP API :

```
$json =
    '{
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "term" : 
                        {
                            "value_of_type" : "sound"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }';
```

But its returning 0 results.
`{"took":4,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}`

The result of hitting `myurl:9200/filebeat` in browser looks like this :

```
{
    "filebeat": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "beat": {
                        "properties": {
                            "hostname": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "version": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "fields": {
                        "properties": {
                            "node": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "value_of_type": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "input_type": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "message": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "offset": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "source": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1494116541083",
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "IdhWgIqiQ-GNrZK3AvCP9g",
                "version": {
                    "created": "5020199"
                },
                "provided_name": "filebeat"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: data is present in the index. the result of hitting `myurl/filebeat/_search` is something like this:
 "hits": {
  "total": 92,
  "max_score": 1.0,
  "hits": [{
   "_index": "filebeat",
   "_type": "doc",
   "_id": "AVvgSgz27_8XwAoIUeKd",
   "_score": 1.0,
   "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2017-05-07T00:23:16.000Z",
    "beat": {
     "hostname": "lorem06",
     "name": "lorem06",
     "version": "6.0.0-alpha1-git3bcebf6"
    },
    "fields": {
     "node": "node1",
     "value_of_type": "sound"
    },
   "input_type": "log", .....
  },  ... .....]

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct, but it doesn't match anything in the index: the documents you have indexed don't have the correct structure.

For you query to match a document, documents in your index should have a `value_of_type` field with value `"sound"` (like returned in the sample response below.)

A simple `GET /filebeat/_search` query (without any filter) should give a result like this:

```
{
   "took": 28,
   "timed_out": false,
   "hits": {
      "total": N, // the number of documents in your index
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         ...
         {
            "_index": "filebeat",
            "_type": "some_doc_type",
            "_id": "some_id",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               ...
               "value_of_type": "sound", // that's what you query will match
               ...
            }
     ]
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, figured it. The updated query with following change works:
`
"term" : 
                        {
                            "fields.value_of_type" : "sound"
                        }`